# Running crons on a scaled mirrored servers (cron logic needed)

Tags: shell, cron, load-balancing

I have a client running on Rackspace, they have three servers that are synced together entirely, I've added a bunch of crons in the crontab using wget to the web address of the cron (that sync to each server). When you go to the client's domain, a load balancer takes care of you.

I only want to run the crons once on one specific server (web01)

Issue is when each server runs the crontabs it gets run x3 for each server. So I put in PHP a check if the hostname is anything other than web01 to die, however since we're using WGET and they are running through the load balancer, we're finding that the LB is sending two requests to web01 and the other to either web02 or web03.

I'm thinking this needs to be done entirely in the crontab checking if the current server is web01 and to run the cron jobs inside the IF statement, otherwise do nothing however I'm not entirely sure the best way to express that with an IF statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three almost-identically configured servers, but you want to run the `cron` jobs on only one of them?

Let's follow your naming scheme for the servers: `web01`, `web02`, and `web03`. I'm using shell script, but the principle is exactly the same for PHP. (I can throw PHP around but I don't consider myself well-versed enough to code it in public.)

Near the top of each `cron` script you can do something like this, which will cause the script to exit unless the server name is `web01`.

```
[ web01 != "$(hostname)" ] && exit
```

This isn't very resilient in the face of a server outage. If `web01` dies you presumably want to pick up the `cron` jobs on another server. Assuming you have access to DNS you can create a CNAME to the server responsible for running `cron`. Here's a sample entry for `bind`; it'll be similar for other systems:

```
cron.contoso.com 300 IN CNAME web01.contoso.com
```

You can then use either `dig` or `nslookup` to compare the server name to the alias, and within five minutes (300 seconds) you can have swapped the responsibilities for `cron` to another server:

```
myaddr="$(nslookup "$(hostname)" | awk '$1=="Address:"{a=$2} END{print a}')"
cronaddr="$(nslookup "$(hostname)" | awk '$1=="Address:"{a=$2} END{print a}')"
[ "$myaddr" != "$cronaddr" ] && exit
```

Or:

```
myaddr="$(dig +short "$(hostname).contoso.com")"
cronaddr="$(dig +short cron.contoso.com)"
[ "$myaddr" != "$cronaddr" ] && exit
```